# XAML List view Inside list view

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this template (c# windows univeral app w8.1)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedSongStanzas}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Verses}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                            <TextBlock Padding="0" Text="{Binding Harmonization2}" FontFamily="Lucida Console" FontSize="16" Foreground="BlueViolet" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
                            <TextBlock Padding="0" Text="{Binding OriginalText}" FontFamily="Lucida Console" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

And This is how it look

[image]

If see at image the first list view item shows the first ListItem lines are together with no spaces between them, but the second line shows a big gap between them.

Note:

1) I'm ,was trying with Grid instead stackpanel but looks same way.

2) If Try fixed height texts could be cut.

What can i do to force all ListItems looks the same way?

(Just Like the firs Item)

**EDIT ONE**: Based on the comments think the problem could be the default styles from windows universal app template. And now could be another question.

How to edit / change / Override  those styles on that template ?

Comment: It is possible that you have some kind of style defined somewhere that add a margin or padding to the TextBlock? On my system there is no vertical space between the white line and the violet line.

Comment: I have made a sample application using same itemssources etc, and found no issue what so ever. Made a sample : https://www.dropbox.com/s/tuxchudjyzlg2ld/WpfListBoxSongs.rar?dl=0

Comment: Tks for your help, I don't have a style defined (not yet) but seems that the universal windows app template has one. How can I Override this style ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally as @AnjumSKhan post, the problem wasn't at XAML code, just my structure Has a Literal char **\n**

Something like this `"some text here"` was stored as => `"\nsome text here"`, just i remove those new lines literals an now all looks as must be.